# Set image in a different way, out of div

Tags: html, css

This is what I have:

[image]

I want it to be:

[image]

Code snippet:

```css
.test0 {
  float: left;
  width: 0%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test0">
  <img src="../arrow.png" height="30px" width="100px">
</div>
```

Really not able to fix this all day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use positioning to achieve this. You need to make the parent div relative and the child have a position of absolute.

See [Codepen](https://codepen.io/DollarChills/pen/JraBMm)

CSS

```
.test0 {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 0%;
  height: 100px;
}
.test0 img {
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
}
```